# Migrate data from SQL 2005 (hosted) to SQL 2008 (in-house server)

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, migration

We have a databased hosted with a "commodity" SQL hosting company.  It's currently hosted on a SQL 2005 server.

We have just configured a dedicated server (to which we have "root" access) running SQL 2008.

Unfortunately, getting a backup file of the SQL 2005 database takes upwards of 3-4 days from the support team.

Is there a better way to connect to our SQL 2005 database, "download" the entire database set, and "import" that data to SQL 2008?

Answer (score 1):

If you can shutdown your site for a couple of hours, you can script out the database, then BCP the actual data from the database tables to flat files on your server, then import these files.  This does require that you have direct access to the SQL Server.

If you can't access the SQL Server directly then you are at the mercy of your hosting company.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below URL http://www.packtpub.com/article/copying-database-sql-2008-copy-database-wizard

Answer (score -1):

If you have someone with the appropriate experience you could look at setting up either log shipping or mirroring. In any case you choose however you are going to have to wait for the data to move across the wire.

The biggest benefit I could see in either of these methods would be that you could minimize the site downtime which is what I believe you are seeking to do. I believe both of these options would require an initial SQL DB Backup to be loaded, but once the syncing started you could probably get away with between 4-12 hours of downtime to be up and running at your new location.

Comment: They aren't going to have the ability to setup either log shipping or database mirroring from a hosting company.